# How to download file from http response with no body

Tags: python, http, insomnia

I have a http response from website that should return excel file.

Status is OK (200) but the body is empty.

[image]

When I check headers there is something what looks like my desired file.

[image]

Only thing I saw how to download was from response body.

I tried this code but it downloads only text from response body (which is in this case none):

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(HOSTNAME)

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'authorization': "Bearer " + getToken()
        }

conn.request("GET", "/dbapi/v4/sql_jobs/export/xlsx/1656366248381_479368648", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

How could I download this file (attachment) with python?

Comment: What code have you attempted to use to download the file?

Comment: I added code but of course far from correct one.

Comment: You can't download a 0-bytes length file